# send array to post ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

i need send mi post in this format

```
{
  "elements" : ["elem1", "elem2","elem3" ]  
}
```

and i have created this array :

```
var miElem=["elem1", "elem2","elem3" ]  

$.post({
          url: 'url',
          data: {"elements" : miElem} ,
          dataType: 'json',

          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)

          }.bind(this),
          error: function(xhr, status, err) {
          console.log(err)
          }.bind(this)
        });
```

but dont work, the data send well, but the format is incorrect

Comment: [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (`$.post()` is just a shortcut for `$.ajax({ type: "post", ... })`): "_**data**: Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. ... Object must be Key/Value pairs._"

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.ajax()` like this.The use of `$.post` is not correct.Check the syntax for `$.post`.here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
var miElem=["elem1", "elem2","elem3"];  

$.ajax({
          url: 'url',//give your url here
          type:'POST',
          data: {elements : miElem} ,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
            alert('success');//test for successful ajax request
            console.log(data);

          },
          error: function(xhr, status, err) {
          alert('error');//test for unsuccessful ajax request
          console.log(err);
          }
       });
```

Comment: if i send other parameter: name, last_name insert well. bat the array no insert, but send well

Comment: r u using PHP  or other language for request?

Comment: don't know in python.But in PHP take reference like..get array using `$elements = $_POST['elements']` and then get each variable using `$elements[0]` so on..

Answer (score 1):

You should used `$.ajax` instead of `$.post`. 
In `$.ajax` don't use success and error parameters. Use `.done()`, `.fail()`, .. (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) it's more comprehensive. You can use `.then()` if you want to use promise.

Datatype parameter is for response type.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is failing because

1. you passed incorrect arguments to `$.post()` method.
2. you did not set `type:'POST'` if you intended to use `$.ajax`.

for `$.post()` do the following:

```
$.post('url', {elements: miElem}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}).fail(function (error) 
  console.error(error);
});
```

for `$.ajax` do the following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'url',
  data: {elements: miElem},
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```